# Как создать сайт на python без использования фреймворков?

Tags: python

Как создать сайт на python без использования фреймворков?

Просто в общем скажите, что нужно сделать. Детали я сам погуглю

P.S. Я знаю, что это создание велосипедов, но это мне нужно для изучения работы веб приложений в частности и обучения программированию в общем

Comment: `python -m pureSite` Только модуль нужно написать

Comment: а чем не устраивает джанго ?

Comment: Изучить спецификацию CGI/WSGI/ASGI (по вкусу), написать код по спецификации и запустить подходящим веб-сервером. Ну или набраться смелости, чтобы изучить спецификацию HTTP и написать свой собственный веб-сервер

Comment: @andreymal HTTP проще чем все вышеперечисленное,)

Comment: @eri триста страниц спецификации HTTP/1.1 это по-вашему проще?) И это я ещё про HTTP/2 не вспоминаю)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Отличный вопрос - зря минусим.

В каталоге проекта

создай папку ./cgi-bin
напиши файлик `./cgi-bin/index.py` с содержимым

```
#!/bin/python3

print("Content-Type: text/html")    # Хидеры ответа
print()                             # Пустая строка сразу после хидеров
# А потом текст ответа
print("<TITLE>CGI script output</TITLE>")
print("<H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>")
print("Hello, world!")
```

Сделай скрипт исполнимым

```
chmod +x ./cgi-bin/index.py
```

И запукай http сервер (можно через apache или lighttpd)

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000
```

Переходи по ссылке http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/index.py и вот Hello-Word на чистом питоне готов.

Вариант чуть посложнее с одним модулем

```
import http.server

class Handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200, 'OK')
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('''
<TITLE>Handler script output</TITLE>
<H1>This is my first Handler script</H1>
Hello, world!
'''.encode())

httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(('', 8000), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Тут нет обработчика URI и один ответ будет на всех страницах.

Answer (score 4):

В стандартной библиотеке Python есть модуль [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html). Это HTTP-сервер, на основе которого можно создавать сайты любой сложности. Конечно, чем больше сложность, тем больше вам придётся написать функциональности, которая уже есть во фреймворках. Но если вам нужен сервер для отладки или вы хотите понять как что устроено, то начните с него.

Answer (score 3):

Если прям без фреймворка, то cgi. Но... зачем? Есть же фреймворки.

- Flask

  > Flask — фреймворк для создания веб-приложений на языке программирования Python, использующий набор инструментов Werkzeug, а также шаблонизатор Jinja2. Относится к категории так называемых микрофреймворков[en] — минималистичных каркасов веб-приложений, сознательно предоставляющих лишь самые базовые возможности.
- Django

  > Django (Джанго, ['dʒæŋɡoʊ][6]) — свободный фреймворк для веб-приложений на языке Python, использующий шаблон проектирования MVC[7]. Проект поддерживается организацией Django Software Foundation.

[django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/) | [flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)

Comment: Какой из них «Без использования фреймворка»?

Comment: @vp_arth Пардон. Сейчас дополню.

Comment: Мне вот интересно - человек спросил как написать "без фреймворка". Может он суть хотел понять, набить себе шишек и написать свой. Но нет, приходит советчик - как же, есть фреймворки, не надо ничего другого. Еще и с википедии копипасту просто вставил.